# Using fminunc function

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

I am trying to use the fminunc function for convex optimization. However, in my case I am taking the gradient with respect with logx. Let my objective function be F. Then the gradient will be

```
dF/dx = (dF/dlogx) * (1/x)
= > dF/dlogx = (dF/dx) * x
```

So

```
logx_new = logx_old + learning_rate * x * (dF/logx)
x_new = exp(logx_new)
```

How can I implement this in fminunc

Answer (score 7):

It's possible and described in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminunc.html):

*If the gradient of fun can also be computed and the GradObj option is 'on', as set by
options = optimset('GradObj','on')
then the function fun must return, in the second output argument, the gradient value g, a vector, at x.*

### fminunc with custom gradient

So for example: if `f = @(x) x.^2;` then `df/dx = 2*x` and you can use

```
function [f df] = f_and_df(x)
    f = x.^2;
    if nargout>1
        df = 2*x;
    end
end
```

You can then pass that function to `fminunc`:

```
options = optimset('GradObj','on');
x0 = 5;
[x,fval] = fminunc(@f_and_df,x0,options);
```

### fminunc with logx gradient

For your logx gradient, this becomes:

```
function [f df] = f_and_df(x)
    f = ...;
    if nargout>1
        df =  x * (dF/logx);
    end
end
```

and the `fminunc` stays the same.

### fminunc with anonymous function

If you want, you can also use anonymous functions:

```
f_and_df2 = @(x) deal(x(1).^2+x(2).^2,[2*x(1)  2*x(2)]);
[x,fval] = fminunc(f_and_df2,[5, 4],optimset('GradObj','on'))
```

### Example of fminunc with logx gradient

Additional example for `f = (log(x))^2`

```
function [f df_dlogx] = f_and_df(x)
    f = log(x).^2;

    df_dx = 2*log(x)./x;
    df_dlogx = df_dx.* x;
end
```

and then:

```
>>x0=3;
>>[x,fval] = fminunc(@f_and_df,x0,optimset('GradObj','on'))
x =
   0.999999990550151

fval =
   8.92996430424197e-17
```

### Example of fminunc with custom gradient and multiple variables

For multiple variables e.g. f(x,y), you'll have to put your variables into a vector, example:

```
function [f df_dx] = f_and_df(x)
    f = x(1).2 + x(2).^2;

    df_dx(1) = 2*x(1);
    df_dx(2) = 2*x(2);
end
```

This function corresponds to a paraboloid.
Of course you'll also have to use a vector for the initial starting parameters, in this case eg: x0=[-5 3]

Comment: I didn't get it. How it is df =  x * (dF/logx). Also if I have more than one variable lets say x,y,z then how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know what your actual function or gradient is, that's why I put in the expression you wrote in your question: `dF/dlogx = (dF/dx) * x`. With `df` in my answer, I mean the actual gradient `df/dx` or for your case the gradient to logx: `dF/dx`. I'll try to give another example in my post